# How to run app Hibernate 5.x, Jpa 2.1, Java EE7(javaee-api 7.0) on Tomcat7 with Jax-RS(Jersey)

Tags: java, tomcat7, java-ee-7, jpa-2.1, hibernate-5.x

I have a simple application runs succesfully as a Java Application. The frameworks used in app Hibernate 5.x, Jpa 2.1, Java EE7(javaee-api 7.0).
And then i wanted to add Jax-Rs support which i want to run it on Tomcat 7.

I got some errors when i want to start application by ServletContextListener. It seems there is no persistence.jar WEB_INF/lib folder but i looked in to folder i has beean created.

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/persistence/Persistence
    at com.ulger.app.EntityManagerFactoryMysql.buildEntiyManagerFactory(EntityManagerFactoryMysql.java:18)
    at com.ulger.app.EntityManagerFactoryMysql.<clinit>(EntityManagerFactoryMysql.java:12)
    at com.ulger.app.Server.configure(Server.java:10)
    at com.ulger.app.Server.start(Server.java:6)
    at com.ulger.app.Initializer.contextInitialized(Initializer.java:10)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4994)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5492)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1575)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1565)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.persistence.Persistence
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1720)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1571)
    ... 14 more
```

The folder of application in tomcat directory

[image]

The deployment descriptor
[image]

Pom.xml

```
    <!-- Database Connector -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.30</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Database Connector -->

    <!-- Javax -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.transaction</groupId>
        <artifactId>jta</artifactId>
        <version>1.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax</groupId>
        <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
        <version>7.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
        <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0.GA</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Javax -->

    <!-- Hibernate -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.1.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
        <version>5.2.1.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate.common</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-commons-annotations</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.1.Final</version>
        <classifier>tests</classifier>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.1-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.1.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-envers</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.1.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Hibernate -->

    <!-- Logging -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.logging</groupId>
        <artifactId>jboss-logging</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Logging -->

    <!-- JAX-RS (Jersey) -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
        <version>1.17.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.17.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-servlet</artifactId>
        <version>1.17.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- JAX-RS (Jersey) -->

</dependencies>
```

Comment: not sure but does tomcat 7 support java EE7

Comment: i will try with higher versions of tomcat

Comment: Only until 6 version

Comment: BTW I notice potential conflict in your libraries. you have JPA 2.0 as well as 2.1 jar. Common annotation has also got 5.0 and 4.0

Comment: i was added it manually. i'll add the right pic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tomcat 7 does not support Java EE 7, and will not load those classes from your WAR. If you reconfigure tomcat to emit debug log output, you should see corresponding warnings about JAR files not being loaded/skipped from your WAR accordingly.

You can either try to downgrade your dependencies to versions which tomcat 7 does support, or you can try to upgrade tomcat to version 8

Comment: i'm trying to run on tomcat 8 and 9. i'm gettng lifecycyle exception.

Comment: Worked on Tomcat 8.5 :)